# Triple bar symbol

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Wikipedia says that-
The triple bar symbol is also sometimes **used in place of an equal sign for equations that define the symbol on the left-hand side of the equation, to contrast them with equations in which the terms on both sides of the equation were already defined.**
Someone please explain the highlighted statement with few examples?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider $f(x)\equiv \sin(x).$ The right hand side of this relation has a clear definition, so this defines $f$. On the other hand, $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ is not defining the left hand side, but is instead an equality that can be proven using the properties of the functions on the left and right hand sides of the equation. The extra line distinguishes this difference in meaning. You might also see $:=$ or $\overset{\Delta}{=}$ used.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Thanks!this makes sense...

Comment: I usually tell my students that there are two uses for "=".  One is "definition", so the equation is always true, the other is "conditional", so we want to know _when_ the equation is true.  If there is confusion, then it's wise to use the triple bar or one of the variations @RideTheWavelet gave.